# Why do i get "error: failed to push some refs"?

Tags: git

I have a remote git repository and a local one that i work with. Whenever i do any changes locally, i push them to the remote. Then i sometime do a "git commit" on the remote one to store the changes on the remote files.

I do not edit the remote repository directly at all. I just commit the changes. And i'm a single developer, no one else works on that repos.

Why do i get an error that, from what i know, means that i have to pull first ?

I don't want to pull because the remote repos files are outdated and it will lose my local changes. This is really annoying, why does this happen ? And how can i fix without having to pull or recreate the repository ? (as you can see, this is sort of like a subversion type of version control style here)

EDIT - The error :

```
To ssh://...
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://...'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: What do you mean you do a "git commit" on the remote repository? Is the remote repository a bare repo? You should generally only be pushing to a bare repo, but you can't commit to a bare repo, so I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do. Can you show an example of the actual commands that you are running and the actual output you are getting?

Comment: well, i was a bit suspicious about that part, that is why i mention it as well. The repos is created with 'git init'. I do a commit on the remote repository, because i don't see the changes in that repository otherwise. I'm adding code to show the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you should be doing is creating the remote repository as a bare repository. A bare repository is just the git repo, without a current checkout (that is, it is like just the contents of the `.git` dir in a regular Git repo, so it contains objects and refs, but it doesn't have an index or working copy of the file hierarchy). If you try pushing to a non-bare repository, the working copy will get out of sync with what is committed, and cause the kinds of problems you are seeing here.

You can create a bare repository using `git init --bare repo.git`. Or you can clone an existing repository as a bare repo using `git clone --bare original-repo new-repo.git`.

If you want to have a checked out copy of the repository on your server, you will need to create a new, non-bare repo on the server, and then pull into that repo from the bare repo that you push to.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, the idea is that the bare repository is like an index that has an internal way of representing the saved data and then you just clone a working (or backup) copy.

Comment: @SpyrosP Basically. A bare repository stores just the history, branches, and tags, but doesn't have any sort of working copy of one particular version, the way a normal repo does. You can clone a bare repo to create a normal repo which has a working copy, that you do your work in.

Comment: Thanx for clarifying, that saves the day for sure :)

Answer (score 8):

this always means that you didn't synchronize the remote repository with local repo,so first you should synchronize them by using command git pull as following:

```
git checkout master    
git pull origin master
```

after this process ,you will synchronize them ,and then you can push changes to remote repo by followings:

```
git add [filename/directory]  
git commit -m"input your message"   
git remote add origin https://github.com//yourname.git     
git push origin master
```

Comment: git push origin master --force , force push worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another option.

```
git reset --mixed origin/master
git add .
git commit -m "Your message"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same error and wasted lots of time, Here is final solution.

1. when use *git push origin master* then we get error so solution is to force push.
   so use second option. it worked for me.
2. git push origin master --force

Comment: This actually worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, and the following command worked.
git push --set-upstream origin master