# heroku push error python 3-6

Tags: python, heroku

I have an issue publishing my python code to heroku
keep in mind that this is my first project on heroku and first with anything to do with repositories

```
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 21.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using python-3.6, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.6) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project.git'
```

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794413/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-com

Comment: Looks obvious that Python 3.6 isn't supported, update it.

Comment: pstatix, I did update it I have 3.6.5 installed

Comment: Got the same issue, I have 3.6.5 specified in the Pipfile but still this error

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
pipenv lock
git add. 
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

If you want a different version, edit the new file and enter the information in:
[requires]
python_version = "2.7" or [requires] python_full_version = "2.7.15"

Answer (score 0):

your requirements.txt file must contain `python-3.6.5` everything in small letters and `-` sign is important

Comment: Make sure you have the python-3.6.5 version installed and not any different version.you can check it by writing ``python --version``  in command prompt