# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failure) error: failed to push some refs to ‘repository URL’

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-push, git-pull

I have already seen the question [failed to push some refs to git@heroku.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794413/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-com) and I'm the only developer of the following private repository which just has a master branch

[image]

From my searches I've seen that this error typically occurs when your local repository is not up-to-date with the remote repository but I have no idea why I am getting this error?

[image]

Comment: @phd I understand but unfortunately I've closed that bash window and cannot paste the code

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Currently, Github has issues. The problem isn't from your side.
(Check [github status](https://www.githubstatus.com/).)

However, In other cases, the problem maybe that remote repository has commits that doesn't exist locally, but in your case, it's github issue.
[image]

---

**UPDATE:**
Github is operational right now.

[image]

Comment: you `git clone`d into another folder and made your changes again and tried to push them again too?

Comment: there it got better. and KZSC keeps hanging up. maybe the interthing just sucks today