# how to solve this error while pushing static files to heroku i get this error

Tags: git, express, heroku, heroku-cli

When I run `git push heroku master`, I get this error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/exampleapp-54011.git'
```

All the files I want to push are in the public folder, this is my `app.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.listen( PORT, ()=> console.log(`server started at port ${PORT}`) );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986139/git-error-when-trying-to-push-pre-receive-hook-declined

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first do a `git pull` then `git push` again.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9794467/16471757