# git pre-receive hook declined with heroku

Tags: wordpress, git, heroku

I've gotten myself into a mess with heroku. I'm deploying a Wordpress PHP app, and basically had a whole bunch of git repos in the theme directory, plus the parent theme which I cloned from a github project. I deployed Wordpress successfully, but git was ignoring the themes that were already tracked in their separate repos, so I went back and copied the themes to a different directory so that they wouldn't be tracked, and deleted the .git folders.

My issue is that after doing this, Heroku won't let me do a `git push heroku master`, but kicks back this error message:

```
Writing objects: 100% (972/972), 2.73 MiB | 76 KiB/s, done.
Total 972 (delta 46), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


To git@heroku.com:....git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:....git'
```

I've tried `git pull heroku master`, which gives me "Already up-to-date." I've also tried to add the `-f` flag, but that doesn't work either. Sometime is rejecting the app within Heroku.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the suggestions here: [failed to push some refs to git@heroku.com:myapp.git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831129/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-commyapp-git)

including creating a new branch from heroku/master and then pushing it immediately to heroku. It fails.

Comment: I ended up just deleting the whole heroku app, creating a new one, linking the remote in git, and uploading it. Seems to work. I had to reconfigure a bunch of stuff, though, and the database had to be rebuilt, so it would be nice to find a way to not do that.

Comment: does this line up time-wise with this status incident? https://status.heroku.com/incidents/513

Comment: Yeah, although it was the afternoon before (Apr 7). Pretty cool site, though, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you tried initialing the repos as submodules and then running a git submodule update?
I know this is a little vague but maybe that will put you in a good direction.

Comment: Were you pushing from your local master branch? If not, `git push heroku master` would push your local master branch to Heroku's master branch, even if you were on a different branch locally. I've had issues with this myself before.

Comment: Yeah, I only had the one branch going. Honestly I'm not even 100% sure I remember what the problem is anymore, but I think it was that I just had the one branch. Unfortunately, I deleted the original heroku branch...I probably could have just found a way to push a new branch to heroku and run off that, but I knew less about git at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Heroku's git infrastructure. For future reference, these are generally service level problems that we monitor, but may be unique to your situation. It's best to check https://status.heroku.com, or file a ticket at https://support.heroku.com.